# Why did the search wildcards function used in an Office taskpane add-in crash Word every time it runs?

Tags: office-js, word-addins

In the Word document, I enter the following content:

```
8-2:1
```

The wildcards search code that crashes Word is as below. I cannot figure out why.

```
let ranges = context.document.body.getRange().getTextRanges([". "], true);
ranges.load();
await context.sync();
let range = ranges.items[0];
let sr = range.search("<[0-9]@-[0-9]@>",{matchWildcards: true});
sr.load();
```

Comment: It looks like you have no ranges that end with ". ", so `ranges.items` is empty.

Comment: Thanks, Rick. But I found it is not empty and console.log(ranges.items[0].text) does produce the content.

Comment: If the only content in the document is `8-2:1`, what content does `ranges.items[0].text` have?

Comment: ranges.items[0].text contains 8-2:1

I forget to mention that there is the by-default paragraph mark at the end. The fact is that even for an empty content  document, Word leaves a paragraph mark there.

Comment: This article [Search options](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/word/search-option-guidance) leads me to think that you need to use parentheses with the `<` and `>` operators. Try `search("<([0-9]@-[0-9]@)>",{matchWildcards: true})`. Another possibility is that you can only use `<` and `>` at the beginning and ending of a word, and maybe Word doesn't regard `8-2` as a word.